# Where is the option 'Display>Only Render" in the latest 2.8 builds?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

Blender 2.79 has the 'Display>Only Render' checkbox in the Properties panel. I am not able to find any such option in the latest Blender 2.8 builds for Eevee. Can someone tell where is it?

Comment: Z then up! - Now you basically just hide overlays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can click on the button next to overlays to hide everything:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but the problem with this is that it will still show objects that have render option disabled. 
"only render" box was super useful to see exactly what the actual render would see, I'm also actively looking for this option in 2.8

Comment: Same here. I can't find a way to do like in 2.79

Comment: That's a misleading answer. Hiding overlays is a completely different thing. Only Render provided functionality to check if the right objects are or are not render visible. Trusting this answer in this kind of workflow where one checks for mistakes before render can lead to problems - imagine if a person trusts this checking of the render visibility before sending their scene to a render farm that costs them money...